# Validate credential against Active Directory fails intermittently

Tags: active-directory

I am using the following code snippet to validate user credentials against the active directory:

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYDOMAIN"))
{
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("user", "password");
    ......
}
```

But the validation fails intermittently. Most of the time it is working. For some users, it returned true some time but it will return false minutes later.

Any ideas what could be the problem?